# Browser tries to load ClojureScript source map from the wrong path

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, source-maps, boot-clj

I'm using Boot to build a Clojure(Script) web app.
The browser loads the transpiled code from http://localhost:8080/main.out/calculators/frontend/core.js

The last line of that file is

```
//# sourceMappingURL=core.js.map
```

I can load that map file from the browser using the URL 
http://localhost:8080/main.out/calculators/frontend/core.js.map

However, if in Chrome Dev Tools' Sources panel I search for the corresponding ClojureScript file, it appears with a wrong URL (see the `main.out/calculators/frontend` nested in itself)
http://localhost:8080/main.out/calculators/frontend/main.out/calculators/frontend/core.cljs

and when loaded, no code is shown and "(source mapped from core.js)" appears in the status bar.

Which could be the problem?

Comment: Could you provide all options you pass to the `cljs` task as well as the .cljs.edn file for your build (assuming you have one)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the version of the ClojureScript dependency in `build.boot` from [1.9.293](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/changes.md#19293) to [1.9.89](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/changes.md#1989) (that's the latest that I found that still works).